# Нажатие одновременно TextView

Tags: android, textview

Есть 2 `TextView`, в `textColor` из папки `drawable` я вставил xml файл

text.xml

> ```
> <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>     <item android:color="@color/color_2" android:state_checked="true" />
>     <item android:color="@color/color_2" android:state_pressed="true" />
>     <item android:color="@color/color_2" android:state_activated="true" />
>     <item android:color="@color/color_0" />
> </selector>
> ```

То есть изначальный цвет черный, при нажатии становится допустим красный, когда отпускаешь обратно становится черный. Так вот, можно ли как-то сделать так чтобы по нажатию на один `TextView`, красным становились оба `TextView` а при отпускании опять становились чёрными.

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView1"
        android:textColor="@drawable/text"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:clickable="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView2"
        android:textColor="@drawable/text"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:clickable="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Вы можете использовать ответ из этой ссылке: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627137/how-can-i-know-when-an-edittext-loses-focus/10627231

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напишите функцию в которой вы находите оба text view и выставьте в них необходимый цвет далее в onCrrate у каждого объекта вызвать

```
textView.setOnClickListener(v - >{
    Ваш метод();
}) ;
```

Comment: по сути получилось но как сделать чтобы при отжатии текст становился обратно чёрным. Я понимаю что нужно использовать `else` но что в нем писать? Если в `if` я использую `isPressed` то в `else` я должен использовать...?

Comment: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/button.php тогда используй OnTouchListener(): и смотри на состояние кнопки через event.

Comment: @Karpuha ответил на вопрос но забыл упоминание прикрепить